# Undefined Property with Custom 404 Page in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I set up a 404_override in my routes.php file. The file is simple:

```
public function missing_page()
{
    $this->output->set_status_header('404');
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('404');
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

If I navigate to a non-existent controller (i.e. /missing-page) the custom 404 method loads properly. If I navigate to an existing controller but a non-existent method (i.e. /not-missing/missing) I get an error:

Codeigniter error log: `Severity: Notice  --> Undefined property: CI_Loader::$user_model /application/views/header.php 30`

PHP error log:
`PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function active() on a non-object in /views/header.php on line 30`

Why would this work fine with one but not the other?

Comment: What is on line 30 of your header.php ?

Comment: `if ( ! $this->user_model->active() ) :`, user_model is loaded according to my CI logs.

Comment: The error is occurring because your header.php expects the user_model to be declared. I am assuming your controllers have something like `$this->load->model('user_model');` in them.

Comment: But if I navigate to a URL that doesn't map to a controller, it works just fine? I'm not passing anything to the view, the model just returns a bool.

Comment: The model is autoloaded and is loaded prior to the error according to the CI logs. Any other thoughts?

Comment: clearly your model is failing to load.

Comment: Try to dump your $this->user_model right before it gets called and navigate to `/not-missing/missing`

Comment: I think it has something to do with a fact that 404 has been called, I think CI suspends everything (maybe for security reasons) models, controlers etc and want to show static 404.

Comment: What you have here is a common issue by CI.
take a look at this link to see what I exactly mean.
https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/1062

Comment: one more thing though. Here's a possible solution, take a look at it.
http://bradym.net/php/custom-error-controller-in-codeigniter-2-0.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html

Stated there that the 404 will be triggered when a controller is not found.

That's why your first scenario works fine.

But in your second scenario, codeigniter found your controller but not your method.

Regards.